# Headphone amplifiers

Tags: headphones

Can a headphone amp help the sound reproduction of even "fairly cheap" (~$100) headphones?

What can a headphone amp help with?  When do I need one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common use for a headphone amp is to feed multiple sets of headphones from a single headphone socket. They can also provide some amplification if your original headphone out signal is too weak.

See this [Sound on Sound article](http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/aug07/articles/qa0807_3.htm) from Martin Walker for a helpful explanation of when you might need a headphone amplifier. Also, check the [Wikipedia article on headphone amps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headphone_amplifier) to understand the two different ways the term is used.